# Developing an application iframe tab

Tags: windows, facebook-like

I know there are several free applications inside facebook  that gives you the facility of if  a user is FAN go to a xyz.php program or shows a image. If the user clicks "like" then go to a vwx.php program or shows a image. I have been trying to do the same as those free applications using FB.Event.subscribe inside a php facebook application but i'm tired of trying. I know it should be as simple as:

**if user is fan** 
{location.href='xyz.php'}
else{location.href='vwx.php'}

**BUT HOW DO I KNOW THE USER IS FAN OR NOT**

please help !!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarise yourself with the *signed_request* parameter:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

If you scroll down the page, you'll find a PHP function that shows you how to verify and decode *signed_request*.

Add the function to your code and call it like this:

```
$data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],'YOUR_APP_SECRET');
```

Now you can access the objects in the signed_request as PHP arrays:

```
if($data['page']['liked']) { //show content for fans } 
else { //show content for others }
```